# How to exclude a specific version of a package that a project dependency uses and override it with a different one?

Tags: npm

I'm running into an issue with my npm mirror.

It appears to be lagging behind. Currently, my Jenkins build fails, because it does not see scheduler@^0.20.2, which was published about 20 hours ago.

Weirdly enough, `npm ls scheduler` returns empty, so I'm not sure what package is requesting it, but I need to, at least for now, somehow specify scheduler@^0.20.1 to be used in my project.

Is there a way to do this? I want to ensure that whichever package it is that depends on scheduler@^0.20.2 will have only scheduler@^0.20.1 available to it.

Answer (score 0):

I just run

```
$ npm install scheduler@0.20.1
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN nm@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN nm@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ scheduler@0.20.1
added 4 packages from 3 contributors and audited 4 packages in 2.939s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

then check

```
$ npm ls
nm@1.0.0 /home/daniil/
└─┬ scheduler@0.20.1
  ├─┬ loose-envify@1.4.0
  │ └── js-tokens@4.0.0
  └── object-assign@4.1.1
```

Editing `package.json` would probably have worked when you need force `deep-lying module` version:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "scheduler": "^0.20.1"
  },
}
```

I solved [this way](https://hackernoon.com/how-fix-security-vulnerabilities-in-npm-dependencies-in-3-minutes-rq9g3y7u) potential vulnerabilities in my repo

Comment: What do you mean? Version 0.20.1 is in the registry [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scheduler), if you navigate to the `versions` tab. I will try your resolutions approach

Comment: @MikeK maybe my internet is buggy

Comment: @MikeK yes, I'm sorry it instlalled now  scheduler@0.20.1